# Hovercards and other hover over image functions don't work anymore!

Tags: javascript

This problem is driving me crazy.
So, I've Jetpack installed and the Gravatar hovercards activated. I could live without them, but other "hover over image" functions (e.g. I'm using the Guan Image Annotation plugin that lets you add a note to an image in a post by hovering over it) don't work either.

It still worked earlier today and all I did was activate and deactivate a few other plugins.
I tried to figure out with plugins are causing the misfunction, but couldn't figure it out. 
Maybe it's not a plugin interfernence after all.
I just can't seem to figure it out :(

As I'm a total beginner I'm not sure, but I think both (hovercards and the mentioned plugin) work with javascript? So maybe something is interfering with that?

I hope you can help me figure this out.
My (under construction) website is [here](http://www.zoomingjapan.com).

Thanks a lot in advance for any kind of advice! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the source code of your homepage, in the header you will see that you have a lot (infact i have never seen as many jquery files in a header before) calls to jquery files, this is definatly a cause for conflict if two of the files are the same, i can see at least 2 references to a similar file.

What you will need to do, is deactivate all plugins, and start reactivating them one by one, each time testing the site, eventually you will activate the plugin that is breaking your jquery what you can do then is open up that plugins files and comment out the line that calls the jquery file and see if it will run off the other one..

these could be the issue
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js?ver=3.2
http://www.zoomingjapan.com/wp-content/themes/alltuts/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js?ver=3.2
http://www.zoomingjapan.com/wp-content/plugins/guan-image-notes/js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.js

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've removed a few of those and I will try deactivating all plugins tomorrow and then let you know.